# Get images from instagram from given hashtag

Tags: android, instagram, instagram-api

I would like to know how do I get images from instagram from given hashtag. I've registered my client and got `CLIENT_ID` and `CLIENT_SECRET`. Then I read about instagram api, and found that I need an `access_token` to search for images. Then that means that I need the user to give an authorization to my app to get their infos. Is there any other work around ? Because, I just want to search for images with given hashtag, it didn't have anything to do with user's information. And to persuade user that they have to provide access just for looking at images, that're not even theirs, is not really persuade.

And, in case that I have to get authorization from the client, what should I put in `redirecturl` ? For now I just fill some random `url` for instagram, because I don't have a server. All run on local phone.

Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may get images by hashtag with [Tag Endpoint](https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/#get_tags_media_recent) without an `access_token`. Just add your `CLIENT_ID` to a query.

Example: `https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/SOMETAG/media/recent?client_id=CLIENT_ID`

Quote from [Instagram API](https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/):

> You're best off using an access_token for the authenticated user for each endpoint, though some endpoints don't require it. In some cases an access_token will give you more access to information (ex: `user_has_liked`), and in all cases, it means that you are operating under a per access_token limit vs. the same limit for your single client_id.